# Cakephp 3.6 Helper that should return model is cast to array in template

Tags: cakephp, helper

Helper:

```
class QuestionHelper extends Helper
{
    protected $_defaultConfig = [];

    public function mostRecentAnswer(Question $q): ?Answer
    {
        $result = (new Collection($q->answers))->max(function($a) {
            return $a->created;
        });
        if ($result) {
            return $result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in a template to display the date, however calling it using property access notation causes an error:

Call: `<td><?= h($this->Question->mostRecentAnswer($question)->created) ?></td>`

Error: `Notice (8): Trying to get property 'created' of non-object [APP/Template\Questions\index.ctp, line 24]`

However, wrapping the returned object in a `dd` shows:

Call: `dd(get_class($this->Question->mostRecentAnswer($question)))`

Result: `"App\Model\Entity\Answer"`

Using array access in the template works:

`<td><?= h($this->Question->mostRecentAnswer($question)['created']) ?></td>`

Is this normal behavior?

Turns out everything was working correctly. The Notice was due to another question, on a different line item, that didn't have any associated answers, and so was returning null. I simply added a wrapper on the helper:

```
public function mostRecentAnswerCreatedDate(Question $q): string
{
    $result = $this->mostRecentAnswer($q);
    if ($result) {
        return $result->created;
    }
    return 'Not yet answered';
}
```

And call it

`<td><?= h($this->Question->mostRecentAnswerCreatedDate($question)) ?></td>`

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually looking at the correct row? If array access works and `dd()` shows that it's an object, then I'd suspect that the error is maybe triggered for a different row where `null` is being returned. Stuff like this can easily be tracked down by using a proper debugger where you can set a breakpoint at the problematic line of code. Also note that all notices come with a stacktrace and code context information, please always include both in your questions - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's exactly what happened; I was checking the wrong item, which was getting a null value. I have added some simple code to fix that! I'll make sure to add the trace in future questions.